# I am not getting output by using find function

Tags: node.js, express

When I run this program with this function, I found no response from the browser.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Product = require('../models/product')
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var assert = require('assert');

  router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Product.find((err, docs) => {
    res.render('shop/index', { title: 'Express', products: docs});
    });
  });

module.exports = router;


index.hbs

{{# each products}}
  products!
{{/each}}
```

I have 5 products in mongoDB , just want to make sure that function get me

products products products products products. In my index page

I want to get products to my index page, but I found nothing.

Comment: Did you console log the “docs” to see that data are actually fetched from database or not? And also try to add your view engine code

Comment: Yes I did, but when I run my program browser show no response.

Comment: Add your view files code, how you are actually rendering them in your index file?

Comment: {{# each products}}
  products!
{{/each}}
  

I just want to make sure that products are fetching with this loop.this is an .hbs file

Comment: you should've fetched your data like this in the hbs file, I'm assuming there is a field called products  in your model , then do this  `{{# each products}} {{this.products} {{/each}} `

Comment: This is not working, I think, something is wrong with this find() function.